# Как вывести строку в файле

Tags: python-3.x

Как вывести первую и вторую строку из файла?

Пример выводит только первую строку

```
f = open('/tmp/vmp-rr-d2.log.1', 'r')
fd = f.readlines(0)
print(fd[0])
```

Comment: `print(fd[1])` - выведет, соответственно, 2-ую. Логично?

Comment: Не выводит. Какое бы значение не ставил, выводит только первую строку. Почему?

Comment: Странно. Попробуйте `f = open(...)    for line in f: print(line)`

Comment: А зачем у Вас `f.readlines(0)`? В смысле - зачем там `0`?

Comment: 0 номер строки, мне нужно вывести 11

Comment: без разницы, хоть ставлю или 0 , 1 или 11

Comment: у меня цель вообще то, в данной строках заменить ip адрес
server.host=127.0.0.1
server.port=6379
server.password=password

Comment: В выражении `f.readlines(0)` `0` - не имеет никакого отношения к номеру строки. Этa функция читает все строки из файла *независимо от аргумента*

Answer (score 1):

```
f = open('/tmp/vmp-rr-d2.log.1', 'r')
fd = f.readlines()
print(fd[i]) --> напечатает i-ю строку файла (начиная с 0)
```

> readlines(...)
>
> ```
> readlines([size]) -> list of strings, each a line from the file.
> Call readline() repeatedly and return a list of the lines so read.
> The optional size argument, if given, is an approximate bound on the
> total number of bytes in the lines returned.
> ```

Не нужно пытаться получить i-ую строку вызовом `f.readlines(i)` - это не так работает.